# How to disable environment rendering in OpenAI Gym?

Tags: python, python-3.x, render, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

I have the following code using OpenAI Gym and highway-env to simulate autonomous lane-changing in a highway using reinforcement learning:

```
import gym

env = gym.make("MountainCar-v0", render_mode='human')
state = env.reset()

done = False
while not done:
    action = 2
    new_state, reward, done, _, _ = env.step(action)

env.close()
```

Here, although I haven't called the `env.render()` method, it still opens a PyGame window and renders. How do I avoid this?

All the existing documentation and issues are relating to the environment NOT rendering (an issue which I also faced in the past, but solved by adding `render_mode = 'human'` in the arguments of `gym.make`), could not find anything related to this.

I get a warning saying that I am using Python 3.6 as my default version which is very minimally supported by OpenAI Gym and that I should upgrade to Python 3.7. Is this related to the issue in any way?

Answer (score 1):

From gym [documentation](https://www.gymlibrary.dev/api/core/) :

Compute the render frames as specified by render_mode attribute during initialization of the environment.
The set of supported modes varies per environment. (And some third-party environments may not support rendering at all.) By convention, if render_mode is:

1. **None** (default): no render is computed.
2. **human**: render return None. The environment is continuously rendered in the current display or terminal. Usually for human consumption.
3. **rgb_array**: return a single frame representing the current state of the environment. A frame is a numpy.ndarray with shape (x,
   y, 3) representing RGB values for an x-by-y pixel image.
4. **rgb_array_list**: return a list of frames representing the states of
   the environment since the last reset. Each frame is a numpy.ndarray
   with shape (x, y, 3), as with rgb_array.
5. **ansi**: Return a strings (str) or StringIO.StringIO containing a
   terminal-style text representation for each time step. The text can
   include newlines and ANSI escape sequences (e.g. for colors).

Comment: Apparently it was possible to render frames step by step before by simply calling env.render() whenever we need since that's what they do in most tutorials. But when we look at the doc we only have the choice between rendering every single episode or none of them.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```py
env = gym.make("MountainCar-v0", render_mode='human')
```

use:

```
env = gym.make("MountainCar-v0")
```

Comment: Hello, please don't just submit code in your answer(s), add some details as to why you think this is the optimal solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm probably following the same tutorial and I have the same issue to enable/disable rendering. So basically my solution is to re-instantiate the environment at each episode with `render_mode="human"` when I need rendering and `render_mode=None` when I don't. It also allows to close the rendering window between renderings.

```py
import gym

env = gym.make("MountainCar-v0", render_mode='human')
state = env.reset()

episodes = 1000
show_every = 200

for episode in range(episodes):
    print(f"Episode {episode}")
    if episode%show_every==0:
        render_mode = "human"
    else:
        render_mode = None
    env = gym.make("MountainCar-v0", render_mode=render_mode)
    state = env.reset()
    terminated = truncated = False
    while not (terminated or truncated):
        action = 2
        new_state, reward, terminated, truncated, _ = env.step(action)

    env.close()
```